# Use nexus with maven-wrapper and docker

Tags: java, spring, docker, maven

I use Maven-wrapper (Spring application). The task is to indicate instead of Maven central, Nexus.
Previously, I did this through Settings.xml, but given that I now have Wrapper and this should live in the docker, it is not very clear where exactly should I enter username / password / url?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

go to your project, and navigate into the .mvn directory. in here make the following files:

**maven.config** containing:

```
-s .mvn/settings.xml
```

**settings.xml** containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
        <username>username</username>
        <password>pass</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>nexus-releases</id>
        <username>username</username>
        <password>pass</password>
    </server>
</servers>
</settings>
```